# Blazor how to submit form without submit button

Tags: .net-core, blazor, submit, fluentvalidation, blazor-editform

In a blazor project I used `Editform` and `Fluentvalidation` as well as [Toolbelt.Blazor.HotKeys](https://github.com/jsakamoto/Toolbelt.Blazor.HotKeys) for a shortcut (ctrl+s) to submit the form
When I press ctrl+s, the *Submit()* method is called, but if the form has an error, it does not show the errors. In fact, only the method is called, not the submit form.
What solution do you suggest for this problem?

```
<EditForm Model="@model" OnValidSubmit="Submit">
            <FluentValidationValidator />
         ...
          <button type="submit" >save</button>
        </EditForm>

@code
{
 [Parameter] public CategoryInfo model { get; set; } = new();
 private async Task Submit()
    {
        var validator = new CategoryValidator();
        var result = validator.Validate(model);
        if (result.IsValid)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please can you post your HotKey setup code for the component.  I'm guessing you're linked the hotkey to the `Submit` method, which doesn't actually submit the form.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis yes i just call Submit method and i tried `_editContext.Validate()` but it always returned `true`

Comment: if `_editContext.Validate()` returns true then the model validates.  If there are errors that are not being reported then there's something wrong with your Fluent Validation code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working single page component that demos the code needed to implement a form submit on `<CTL>S`.  I've used the `DataAnnotationsValidator` for simplicity.   There are inline comments to explain the methods.

```
@page "/"
@implements IDisposable
@using Toolbelt.Blazor.HotKeys
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

<h3>EditForm</h3>

<EditForm EditContext="this._editContext" OnValidSubmit="ValidSubmitForm" OnInvalidSubmit="InvalidSubmitForm">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <div class="p-2">
        <span>Value (100-200):</span>
        <InputNumber @bind-Value="_model.Value" />
        <ValidationMessage For="() => _model.Value"/>
    </div>
    <div class="m-2 p-2">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</EditForm>
<div class="m-2 p-2">
    <span>@message</span>
</div>
<div class="m-2 p-2">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" @onclick="SubmitFormExternally">Submit Form Externally</button>
</div>


@code {
    private string message;

    private Model _model = new Model();

    [Inject] private HotKeys hotKeys { get; set; }

    private HotKeysContext _hotKeysContext;

    EditContext _editContext;

    // Explicitly setup the Edit context so we have a reference to it
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _editContext = new EditContext(_model);
        _hotKeysContext = this.hotKeys.CreateContext()
         .Add(ModKeys.Ctrl, Keys.S, SubmitFormCtlS, "Submit form");

    }

    // Invalid handler
    private Task ValidSubmitForm()
    {
        message = $"Valid Form Submitted at :{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}";
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    // Valid Handler
    private Task InvalidSubmitForm()
    {
        message = $" Invalid Form Submitted at :{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}";
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    // Method to call from external button
    // Works and component updates as it's a Blazor Component event
    // emulates the private HandleSubmitAsync method in EditForm
    private async Task SubmitFormExternally()
    {
        if (_editContext.Validate())
            await this.ValidSubmitForm();
        else
            await this.InvalidSubmitForm();
    }

    // Method to call from shortcut key
    // The shortcut key mechanism does't wrap the call in a Blazor Component event
    // So we wrap the code within one
    // The code emulates the private HandleSubmitAsync method in EditForm
    private async Task SubmitFormCtlS()
    {
        var task = Task.CompletedTask;
        if (_editContext.Validate())
            task = this.ValidSubmitForm();
        else
            task = this.InvalidSubmitForm();
        this.StateHasChanged();
        if (!task.IsCompleted || task.IsCanceled)
        {
            await task;
            this.StateHasChanged();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _hotKeysContext.Dispose();
    }

    // Quick Model Class
    public class Model
    {
        [Range(100, 200, ErrorMessage = "Must be between 100 and 200")]
        public int Value { get; set; } = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but im using `FluentValidationValidator` :)

Comment: Same thing.  Replace `DataAnnotationsValidator` with `FluentValidationValidator` and do the validation on your model.  I used `DataAnnotationsValidator` because I can keep all the demo code together and it's very simple to use in a demo.